# How do I control the style of the clone of a draggable div when moved to a sortable container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, jeditable

What I'm trying to do is combine two projects:

- [One is an example of draggable and sortable list-items](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable)
- [The other is jEditable, which I'm using to make the list-items editable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)

Now I was able to append the edit class to the existing list items in the first link without any trouble. When I go to create a new draggable item (a clone) and move it to the sortable list, I want it to take on the css class of the older items. I have tried adding code to the draggable's stop event and the sortable's receive event with no luck. It's the original's style that changes, not the clone's.

```
                receive: function(event, ui) {
                alert("dropped item ID: " + ui.item.attr('id'));
                $("#draggable").attr('class', 'edit');
                }

stop: function() {
                    if ( !$( "#draggable" ).hasClass( "ui-state-hover" ) ) {
                        $( "#draggable" ).removeClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
                        $( "#draggable" ).addClass( "ui-state-default" );
                        $( "#draggable" ).addClass( "edit" );
                    }
                }
```

How can I achieve this?

[JSFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/xvsMh/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually utilize the `ui` in your sortable event `stop`. Here short definition of them:

```
ui.
helper: The jQuery object representing the helper being sorted
item: The jQuery object representing the current dragged element
offset: The current absolute position of the helper represented as { top, left }
position: The current position of the helper represented as { top, left }
originalPosition: The original position of the element represented as { top, left }
sender: The sortable that the item comes from if moving from one sortable to another
```

So you need to use stop event and change the `ui.item` style like this:

```
$(ui.item).attr('class', 'ui-state-default edit');
```

And you have to re-initiate the editable like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initEditable();
});

function initEditable(){
    $('.edit').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', {
        indicator : 'Saving...',
        tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
    });
    $('.edit_area').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', { 
        type      : 'textarea',
        cancel    : 'Cancel',
        submit    : 'OK',
        indicator : '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
        tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
    });
}


$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        revert: true,
        update: function() {
            var orders = [];
            $.each($(this).children(), function(i, item) {
                orders.push($(item).data("x"));
            });
            $("#info").text("Order: " + orders.join(","));
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.item).attr('class', 'ui-state-default edit');
            initEditable();
        }
    });
});
```

See modified code here: http://jsfiddle.net/xvsMh/1/

Comment: well explained, and JSFiddle works as expected. Thanks, SubRed

Comment: Actually, I just noticed. Looks like when you try to rearrange the items within the sortable, just before you let them go (the stop event), it turns into an edit box. Is there any way of fixing this?

Comment: @Freakishly see here modified fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xvsMh/2/. One of easiest approach :) you can simply unbind click event to the item dragged. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks I will mark your answer as right answer. See my updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/parikramatic/eWwPk/10/ Next I am trying to delete a list item by displaying an image on hover, but it's appending to the <li> and looks bad on edit. Please take a look, or I will probably end up asking another question. Thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: @Freakishly you are welcome. I have looked at your fiddle, but can you be clearer what you are trying next?

Comment: Hello SubRed, I am using the fcbkcomplete plugin: I have a new JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/parikramatic/z4jpH/ I can't seem to do much after adding the 'ui-state-default class' in the stop event of $("#sortable").sortable. I'm trying to copy just the text ('execute') without any extra decoration or input boxes.

Answer (score 2):

Your events are correct, but as you realized, #draggable is the original item, not the cloned one. One way to get your cloned item would be to search for an item with identical classes in the sortable list. So instead of using:

```
$("#draggable").attr('class', 'edit');
```

you use:

```
$('#sortable .ui-draggable')
  .removeClass('ui-state-highlight ui-draggable')
  .addClass('ui-state-default edit');
```

[Demo at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxB5P/)

Comment: Thanks for replying, Tyron. I tried the demo, and while the pasted item has the new visual class, the 'edit' class is not applied.